# Android: WindowManager BadTokenException

Tags: android, view, android-windowmanager

I have reviewed every post about this exception of AlertDialog and spent 2 days to trace issue but could'nt. Can anyone see something i miss here?

Popup is displaying from Fragment and having the context of Parent-Activity.

```
IBinder token = rootView.getWindowToken(); //not null
mWindow.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
```

**Statc Trace:**

```
11-24 10:12:18.937: W/System.err(13061): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@46b62c00 is not valid; is your activity 

running?
11-24 10:12:18.937: W/System.err(13061):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563)
11-24 10:12:18.937: W/System.err(13061):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
11-24 10:12:18.937: W/System.err(13061):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-24 10:12:18.947: W/System.err(13061):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1041)
11-24 10:12:18.947: W/System.err(13061):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:877)
11-24 10:12:18.947: W/System.err(13061):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:841)
11-24 10:12:18.947: W/System.err(13061):    at com.test.hpi.DisplayPopup.displayPopup(DisplayPopup.java:181)
11-24 10:12:18.947: W/System.err(13061):    at com.test.hpi.AddModifyAllergypopup.showdropdownlist(AddModifyAllergypopup.java:1038)
11-24 10:12:18.957: W/System.err(13061):    at com.test.hpi.AddModifyAllergypopup.access$35(AddModifyAllergypopup.java:999)
11-24 10:12:18.957: W/System.err(13061):    at com.test.hpi.AddModifyAllergypopup$9.onClick(AddModifyAllergypopup.java:348)
11-24 10:12:18.957: W/System.err(13061):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
11-24 10:12:18.957: W/System.err(13061):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
11-24 10:12:18.957: W/System.err(13061):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-24 10:12:18.967: W/System.err(13061):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-24 10:12:18.967: W/System.err(13061):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-24 10:12:18.967: W/System.err(13061):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
11-24 10:12:18.967: W/System.err(13061):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:12:18.967: W/System.err(13061):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-24 10:12:18.967: W/System.err(13061):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
11-24 10:12:18.977: W/System.err(13061):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-24 10:12:18.977: W/System.err(13061):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post more code? like what is mWindow

Comment: I solved it, Thanks for comment, issue was in rootView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i made it work :)

> RootView must be the view from which DialogWindow has to be opend,

I was passing wrong view as rootView